# jQuery: How to create a single-click dropdown menu with an href title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a dropdown menu with the following behavior:

- Single-click - opens a submenu
- Double-click - opens a link

Currently, double-clicking the link works but the submenu doesn't open. How can I best create the desired effect considering my below code?

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 3</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul

.submenu{
        display: none;
    }

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').show();

    $(".menu > li > a").attr("data-count", "0");
    $(".menu > li > a").on("click", function(){

    var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
    clickCount ++;
    if (clickCount == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-count", clickCount);
      return false
    } else {
      return true;
    }
});
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add one line to your `click` handler:

```
    $(this).next('.submenu').show();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').show();

  $(".menu > li > a").attr("data-count", "0");
  $(".menu > li > a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next('.submenu').show();
    var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-count", clickCount);
      return false
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu 3</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="li"><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to count the clicks manually if youre using jquery, there is already an event..

for one click use the click event, for 2 clicks use the dblclick event.

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: A `dblclick` is two clicks in rapid succession, which is different than two clicks several seconds apart.